# Typical (cell-phone quality) audio modules and formats

Tags: audio, integrated-circuit

My question is twofold :-)

What are typical audio modules that I can use in a lo-fi electrical application to playback some simple music (of about 1 minute)? Think of cellphone speaker quality.

What is the digital format of this audio? I spoke with an electrical engineer and he mentioned PCM A-Law. which sounds reasonable due to the small usage. Are there any other formats available? Another tip I got was MIDI, but I think that using a wavetable limits the music capability but makes it easier.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Accepting answers early may prevent others giving you other good replies. (I'm happy but ... :-) ). What part of the answer did you like? ISC ICs or PIC ADPCM or ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) You can have all the hard work done for you by eg products like the

- [ICD Chipcorder range of ICS](http://www.nuvoton-usa.com/hq/enu/ProductAndSales/ProductLines/ConsumerElectronicsIC/ISDVoiceIC/ISDChipCorder/)

I have no 'interest' in the company apart from having used their voice recorder ICs in the past with good results.

The basic ICs are essentially standalone and function conceptually  as multimessage electronic tape recorders. They are usually combined with a microcontroller but do not need to be in many cases.

They say:

- Non-volatile message storage
- 6 Seconds to 64 Minutes Record and Playback Durations
- 4.0 to 32KHz Sampling Frequency provides
  Industry-Leading Sound Quality
- Built-in Message Management for
  Single/Multiple messages
  Fully Integrated System Functions
- AGC, Microphone preamplifier
- Speaker drivers
- Low Voltage Operation

Their MLS ICs store the signal as analog levels in flash memory (good trick) and they also have a range of full digital recorders.

They have versions which use external SD Flash storage

BUT

(b) You can now get standard routines which allow operation of SD Flash from even relatively low performance microcontrollers. Direct memory fetch and output to DAC (on board or external - can be as simple as an R-2R resistor network and an opamp) and you have audio out. About 500 kB of flash for one minutes at 8 kB/second.

A-law and u-Law are curve shaping schemes which allow you to store a wider dynamic range within 8 bits. For what you are describing you can probably accept simple 8 bit store and output. But, A-law is essentially a lookup table.

You did not say if this is store once and play often or needs to be field recordable. If play once then a MIDI or other tune synthesizer takes far less memory and can be implemented withing many microcontrollers.

(c) You can play with ADPCM and fewer bits per sample and more **but** for your needs it's likely that off the shelf code and hardware will do the job. Acceptable cost is an issue - clever methods would allow a very low cost solution using a microcontroller.

(d) A web search is highly likely to turn up many DIY record and playback systems.

[Low cost PIC speech recorder - 1999 - Circuit Cellar](http://www.circuitcellar.com/library/print/0999/richey110/4.htm)

[PIC32 audio library](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1824&appnote=en534485)

Application note - 1997~ -  [Microchip ANM643 - ADPCM using PICs](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00643b.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! It is a store once play often solution I am looking for. Think of the quality expected from general kid toys that play music.

Comment: @avanwieringen - Then the answer at the end of (b) is probably most appropriate. If each note is described by its attributes (eg frequency, volume, duration, maybe wave shape if you want to be fancy). May take say 4 bytes per note. If you played at 10 notes per second (fast!) you'd need 4bytes/note x 10notes/second x 60s = 2400 bytes. Less probably.